# Getting null result from SQL Server stored proc which returns XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

I have a stored proc which returns a piece of XML. It works fine when I execute it from MS SQL Management Studio.
I need to write some C# code to execute the proc and take the resulting XML and write it to a file.
I wrote the code and it executes the proc (I checked using the profiler), and there is no error, but the XmlReader is empty.
My code is something like:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(-snip-))
{
c.Open();
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_formfill_contract_xml", c);

myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i_contract_id", frm_contract_id.Text.ToString());                    

System.Xml.XmlReader xmlr = myCommand.ExecuteXmlReader();
xmlr.Read();


while (xmlr.ReadState != System.Xml.ReadState.EndOfFile)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(xmlr.ReadOuterXml());
    // do stuff with the XML snippet here
    }

    c.Close();
    }
```

As a comparison test I created a 2nd stored proc which returns a plain string containing the XML that the 1st proc generates, and the C# code receives that just fine, so long as I don't use the XML reader. So it's something to do with the kind of data that the XML proc is returning which makes it appear empty.

Any ideas?
-Sean

Comment: what version of sql-server? Are you returning as XML the select ? http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1077/returning-xml-result-sets-with-sql-server/ or as plain text (varchar)?

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the reason why it should not work my only guess is that you must had one row and you already went to endoffile calling xmlr.Read(); so please try the below way

```
using(System.Xml.XmlReader xmlr = myCommand.ExecuteXmlReader())
{
 while xmlr.Read())
 {
    MessageBox.Show(xmlr.ReadOuterXml());
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion but got the same result. At least, the while() never evaluated to true, so the Read must be returning EOF. I'm not trying to do anything fancy with the XML, I just want to store it in a String or a file so that I can overwrite the content of an existing XML file with it. I'm not planning to do any analysis of the XML in memory. Maybe there is a better way of doing this? Do you know if there's a way I can tell SQL Server to return the result as a string for example?

Comment: you can convert the xml to string in sql like this CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), @xml, 1); if thats what your are after

Comment: Thanks again. I tried it. But it didn't make any difference. I'm bewildered! Another proc I coded, which just returns a hard-coded XML works fine, but this proc, which uses the 'FOR XML' clause, then converts the result to VARCHAR, before passing it back, doesn't work.

Comment: What I have found is that the Read doesn't fail, it works, but just returns an empty value